# Creating vector with minimum values of another vector [R]

Tags: r, minimum

I have a problem that is very simple, but curiously it is taking me longer than I imagined. I'll put it generically here, and in the end I put an example. I hope to be clear:

I have a numeric vector `X1`, with N observations. I need to create another vector, `X2`, based based on minimum value of vector `X1`.

But the condition is a little strange: every observation of this vector `X2` must be the minimum value of the last 126 observations of vector `X1`, in the same position.

In other words, each observation `i` of vector `X2` is the result of the minimum between `(i-125):i` of vector `X1`.

I have tried in many ways, by for, creating functions and using apply, using index, but it did not work.

Consider the example:

```
set.seed(1)
x1<-rnorm(500,2,3)
i<-seq(126,length(x1))
x2<-min(x1[(i-125):i])
```

and the warning msgs:

```
Warning messages:
1: In (i - 125):i :
  numerical expression has 375 elements: only the first used
```

or

```
for(j in 126:length(x1)){
  x2<-rep(NA,length(x1))
  x2[j]<-(min(x1[j-125:j]))
}
```

In this case, only the last observation (500) which does not result in `NA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop should have had the same parentheses you had in the attempt that prompted the warnings (and should NOT have initialized the vector inside the for-loop, since that erased the prior values.):

```
x2<-rep(NA,length(x1))
for(j in 126:length(x1)){

  x2[j]<-(min(x1[(j-125):j]))
}
```